# "nokia.map is undefined" error while implementing tutorial

Tags: javascript, here-api

While trying to implement the examples at https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/maps/topics/building-on-simplest-scenario.html I get the error `"nokia.map undefined"` in the js console.

Answer (score 0):

replace `nokia.map.Display` with `nokia.maps.map.Display`. Maybe someone at Nokia can update the tutorial.